# Dismissing a custom dialog from RunOnUiThread after N seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom dialog and it's being created by the code below:

```
public DialogFragment CreateNewPostedMessageDialog(CardSwipeData data, 
    List<MessagesMap> messagesMap, 
    string fbProfileimageAsByteString, 
    Context context) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = 
                new NewPostedMessageDialogFragment(data, messagesMap,
                                                   fbProfileimageAsByteString, 
                                                   context);
            return newFragment;
        }
```

It's called from my Activity's OnResume RunOnUiThread:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    // Processing stuff here               

    RunOnUiThread(() => {
        DialogFragment dialog = CreateNewPostedMessageDialog(cardSwipeData,
           messagesMap, bitmapByteString, this);

        dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "PostedMessage");

        // ListAdapter gets updated here

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        dialog.Dismiss();
    });
});
```

I want to dismiss my dialog after 3 seconds, but what's happening is my dialog never shows up but my list still gets updated after 3 seconds. Anything I'm doing wrong with the sleep?

Comment: Use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) postDelayed method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong there is that you are sleeping the UI thread and not the background thread you have spawned in the `TreadPool`. Try with this instead:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    // Processing stuff here               

    DialogFragment dialog;

    RunOnUiThread(() => {
        dialog = CreateNewPostedMessageDialog(cardSwipeData,
           messagesMap, bitmapByteString, this);

        dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "PostedMessage");
    });

    // ListAdapter gets updated here
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    RunOnUiThread(() => dialog.Dismiss()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that more than one UI thread can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Since `runOnUiThread` runs on the UI thread

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

blocks the UI thread for three seconds, making the UI unresponsive .  If you want to dismiss the Dialog after three seconds you can use the p`ostDelayed()` from the Handler class:

```
Declare an Handler handler = new Handler();
```

then, inside the `runOnUiThread` change the code you post with:

```
   {

      final DialogFragment dialog = CreateNewPostedMessageDialog(cardSwipeData,
       messagesMap, bitmapByteString, this);

     dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "PostedMessage");

    // ListAdapter gets updated here

     handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
             dialog.Dismiss();
          }
     }, 3000) ;

});
```

check for typo